# I want to understand Python prediction model

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to code a predictive model and i Found this code somewhere and wanted to know what it does mean please. Here it is "X_train.reset_index(inplace = True)"?

Comment: It resets the index of the training pandas dataframe or series I can't tell which you have from the one line of code. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html. In the future more code/information will help us answer the question more accurately

Answer (score 1):

I think it would help if you provide more context to your question. But in the meanwhile, it seems that the line of code that you have shown here is enumerating the training dataset of whatever model you're working with (usually `X` denotes the data and `Y` denotes the labels).

The dataset is a pandas `DataFrame` object, and the `reset_index` function enumerates the items in the `DataFrame` so that each item in the `DataFrame` is numbered instead of named. You can find more information about this in the documentation for this method:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Actually i am a beginner, and i am currently trying to find a code; python based; that allows to predict results based on a specific dataset. I would like u to share your experience with me ?